# Other than it being bad naming convention, what is the harm in using variable names like data type names (example: datetime, str, int)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Other than it being bad naming convention, what is the harm in using variable names like data type names (example: date, str, int)?

Example:

```
str = 'some string'
int = 10    
datetime= datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17)
```

Comment: It overwrites the built-in object or type.  Try it.  Convert ‘11’ to an `int` after assigning `int` to a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “harm” is that you are shadowing the builtin names, and can’t use them any more in the same scope as the variables.

That said, for very small scopes this is arguably fine, though some people disagree — it’s a matter of stylistic opinion. For example, some people would feel fine calling a general-purpose string argument to a function `str`. Others object.

Comment: Since there is no python type called "date" - I suppose it is OK to use date as variable name?

Comment: @variable If the variable is descriptive enough for its purpose, sure!

Answer (score 1):

I don't work in Python, so don't if that's is possible, but I will assume it is...

The harm is for the eyes of the developer that reads the code.

Variable names SHOULD be something with meaning, like:

```
string virus_name;
int countries_affected;
date last_virus_spotted_day;
```

This makes things understable for anyone reading the code, a code reviewer, or the same person reading in 2 years time what they tried to do.

Comment: OK but what do you call the argument to a function `to_uppercase`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph in dotnet we usually use "the" and the type name, like to_uppercase(string the_string)

Comment: @S3DEV I … disagree. In fact, I was about to amend my own reply with the information int his answer.

Comment: @S3DEV that's why I said I don't work in Python to start.. but I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these variable names but then you won't be able to use those builtin functions as long as your variables are in scope. As long as you are ok with that (and with the fact that others really won't like your variable naming choice :)), you should be ok

Comment: They’re not keywords.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in functionality behind those names, by using them as a variable name, you will override their main functionality.

take a look at this:

```
In [1]: a = list()  # main functionality                                                                                                                         

In [2]: a                                                                                                                                   
Out[2]: []          # result

In [3]: list = 2    #overriding `list`                                                                                                                             

In [4]: b = list()  # it is like typing 2()   
                                                                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-650a10196a8c> in <module>
----> 1 b = list()

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

It overwrites the built-in object or type.  Try it.  Convert ‘11’ to an `int` after assigning `int` to a value.

```
int = 11
int('11')
>>> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```